# How to update Visual Studio project files from Azure server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 website being hosted for free in Azure.

In my Visual Studio project solution there are some CSV files I use for data storage(instead of a SQL Server database to keep the website free) and these files are modified by users.

How do I update my local files with the files in the Azure server. Or better yet, how do I get any changes made in the Azure server to my local Visual Studio solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Azure SDK installed you should be able to browse via the Server Explorer in Visual Studio. It will let you connect right to your account and browse websites, storage etc..

[image]

The other option is connecting via FTP using the deployment credentials in the azure portal.